# How can I use deep links in Mongo Stitch Email Confirmation URLs?

Tags: mongodb, expo, mongodb-stitch

I want to configure a Mongo Stitch App to confirm users via e-mail. 
I'd like to use a deep link to link directly into my react native expo app.
During development the link would be "exp://localhost:19000/".
The link correctly reaches my app.

Unfortunately Stitch under "Auth Providers > Edit local-userpass" does not accept this link. The error message is:

> "Please enter a URL beginning with a valid scheme such as https:// or
>   http://"

To replicate this error:

1. Setup a stitch app as described in the docs: https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/stitch
2. In the stitch settings under "Users > Providers" enable "Email/Password" and go into the config settings for this authorization method. There, choose "Send a confirmation email".
3. You are now prompted to configure a "Email Confirmation URL". Apparently this can not be a deep link to an expo app. The link needs to start with http or https but expo deep links start with "epx" as outlined here https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/linking/#linking-module.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should provide more details and show your codebase that will give a more clear idea about your issue and what the configuration parameters you have set.

Comment: The issue is not related to my specific code. The question is if it is possible to use deep links in general. According to the documentation it should work (docs.mongodb.com/stitch/authentication/userpass/index.html). I added the exact steps to replicate this. I think it is a configuration issue, not a coding issue.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the only URL schemes supported for Email Confirmation URL is `http` and `https`.

However, you can create a custom flow using [Run A Confirmation Function](https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/authentication/userpass/index.html#run-a-confirmation-function). Whenever a new user registers an account, the custom confirmation function will be executed with the tokens. The function could send an email containing a deep link and set the registration status to `pending`.

Then the client application must call the `confirmUser` SDK function to fully confirm the user’s identity and allow login. For an example of user confirmation, see [Confirm a New User’s Email Address](https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/authentication/userpass/index.html#auth-confirm-email-address).

Comment: Thanks! My reputation is to low to upvote but I appreciate it.